# How can I save UTF-8 files without converting characters to escaped unicode characters in Java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to save YAML files with UTF-8 characters but characters are automatically turning into escaped unicode characters.

For example:

```
&4&l➸ &5&lLegendary Crate
```

turns into:

```
&4&l\xe2\ufffd\xb8 &5&lLegendary Crate
```

But when I run my program from Intellij IDEA with Run button it saves the files the way it originally is.

I'm using [Bukkit API's FileConfiguration class](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/configuration/file/FileConfiguration.html) to save YAML files.

Here is my code:

```
private Map<String, FileConfiguration> configurations = new HashMap<>();
private void saveConfig(String fileName) {
    try {
        configurations.get(fileName).save(new File("db/", fileName));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't save! Exception: " + ex);
    }
}
```

I'm assuming it might be solved with launch parameters but `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` didn't do any help.

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently you should add launch parameters before `-jar <program>.jar`.

`java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar <program>.jar` solved the issue for me.